# How do I get acces to chrome notifications API in my chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, notifications

According to: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications I need to do something like this:

```
const notification = () => {
  var options = {
      type : "basic",
      title : "Some title",
      message: "Some message",
      iconUrl: "icons/icon19.png" // YES this png does exist
  }
  chrome.notifications.create(
      'id_1',
      options,
      function() {
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
      }
    );
}
```

However, when I run my extension I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined`

I have added "notifications" to my permission in `manifest.json`

```
"permissions": [
    "https://target-site.org/*",
    "notifications"
  ],
```

I have also tried to do `console.log(chrome);`

Which returns an object that does NOT contain notifications. This is what it outputs:

[image]

How do I get access to notifications in my chrome extension project?

Comment: Content scripts can't use most of extensions APIs. Use a background or browser_action script.

Comment: Thanks! will try